# Trouble exporting data from Redshift using PSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psql

I can connect to redshift using psql. Once connected, I am trying to run the following command:

```
copy (select * from *tablename* limit 10) to '/home/*path*/test.csv' with csv
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
```

and I cannot work out why I am getting this error.

I'm not sure if I need an s3 account to copy to? or if I am able to copy directly from redshift to my local machine - these [resource 1](https://www.periscopedata.com/amazon-redshift-guide/importing-and-exporting-data) and [resource 2](http://www.codezuzu.com/2015/04/how-to-importexport-data-from-amazon-redshift/) seem to indicate that I need an s3 account?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can only export data from Amazon Redshift to S3 as per [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

An alternative method seems to be if, whilst in psql, logged into Redshift:

```
=# \o *directory*/filename.csv
=# *query*;
=# \o
```

This seems to export the data directly from redshift into a file on my local machine.

If you want an unaligned output, you can use the following

```
=# \a \o *directory*/filename.csv
=# *query*;
=# \o
```

I won't mark this as answered just yet, in case there is a better answer.